# How do I rearrange HTML with PHP or regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have different outputs of `$slider['image']`. Two examples are as follows.

The first one has `<p>` and `</p>` at the beginning and at the end.
In the second one, all `<img>` tags have `<p>` and `</p>` tags.

### One

```
<p>
    <span>Homepage</span><img src="../../assets/images/prints/print2_600x300.gif" alt="" width="600" height="300">
    <span>Content Page</span><img src="../../../assets/images/support_images/imageA_600x300.gif" alt="" width="600" height="300">
    <span>Dropdown Menu</span><img src="../../../assets/images/support_images/imageB_600x300.gif" alt="" width="600" height="300">
    <span>Comments List</span><img src="../../../assets/images/support_images/imageC_600x300.gif" alt="" width="600" height="300">
    <span>Comment Form</span><img src="../../../assets/images/support_images/imageD_600x300.gif" alt="" width="600" height="300">
</p>
```

### Two

```
<p><span>Homepage</span></p>     
<p><img src="../../assets/images/prints/print2_600x300.gif" alt="" width="600" height="300"></p>
<p><span>Content Page</span></p>  
<p><img src="../../../assets/images/support_images/imageA_600x300.gif" alt="" 
width="600" height="300">
<p><span>Dropdown Menu</span></p>
<p><img src="../../../assets/images/support_images/imageB_600x300.gif" alt="" width="600" height="300"></p>
<p><span>Comments List</span></p>
<p><img src="../../../assets/images/support_images/imageC_600x300.gif" alt="" width="600" height="300"></p>
<p><span>Comment Form</span></p>
<p><img src="../../../assets/images/support_images/imageD_600x300.gif" alt="" width="600" height="300"
```

I need to change this to the following.

```
<li><span>Homepage</span><img alt="" src="assets/images/prints/print2_600x300.gif" /></li> 
<li><span>Content Page</span><img alt="" src="assets/images/support_images/imageA_600x300.gif" /></li> 
<li><span>Dropdown Menu</span><img alt="" src="assets/images/support_images/imageB_600x300.gif" /></li> 
<li><span>Comments List</span><img alt="" src="assets/images/support_images/imageC_600x300.gif" /></li> 
<li><span>Comment Form</span><img alt="" src="assets/images/support_images/imageD_600x300.gif" /></li>
```

I assume I may need regex and php (`explode`, `str_replace`, `foreach`) for this but I need some help.

Full output:

```
[0] =>; Array
    (
        [id] => 12
        [name] => Print 2
        [shortdesc] => <p>Print 2 short description</p>
        [longdesc] => <p>Print 2 long description</p>

        [thumbnail] => <p><img src="../../assets/images/prints/thumbnails/print2_223x112.gif" alt="" width="223" height="112"></p>
        [image] => <p><img src="../../assets/images/prints/print2_600x300.gif" alt="" width="600" height="300">Homepage<img src="../../../assets/images/support_images/imageA_600x300.gif" alt="" width="600" height="300">Content Page<img src="../../../assets/images/support_images/imageB_600x300.gif" alt="" width="600" height="300">Dropdown Menu<img src="../../../assets/images/support_images/imageC_600x300.gif" alt="" width="600" height="300">Comment List<img src="../../../assets/images/support_images/imageD_600x300.gif" alt="" width="600" height="300">Comment Form</p>
        [product_order] => 0
        [class] =>
        [grouping] =>
        [status] => active
        [category_id] => 5
        [featured] => front
        [other_feature] => none
        [price] => 0.00
    )
```

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is painful...

Comment: Please use a DOM parser in conjunction with XPath to parse HTML. PHP has one, (`DOMDocument`), so forget that regex idea completely, you are wasting your time. HTML is not text, HTML is a markup language, and as such it *cannot successfully be parsed by regular expressions*. Which is repeated on this site and elsewhere probably a thousand times a day.

Comment: Take a hint from quite possibly the single most upvoted answer on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Maybe I'm being blind but your "full out put" has images *before* headings, whereas your question has images *after* headings; or at the least, no image after "Comment Form". Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Expect for very simple tasks, it won't be easy to do what you want with regex.

You can use an XML parser like [SAX](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) or [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

You can also take a look to these two library :

- [phpHTMLParser](http://www.onderstekop.nl/articles/114/)
- [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: The PHP DOMDocument reads invalid HTML too, up to a certain extent. Everything else can be passed through tidy first to make absolutely sure.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php - quote: "Unlike loading XML, HTML does not have to be well-formed to load."